# What are the effect of microtubule or microfilament inhibition on yeast expression profile?

Tags: cell-biology, gene-expression, yeast, cytoskeleton

I was wondering whether anyone has looked at what are the expression changes in yeast when the microtubule or the microfilament polymerization is inhibited? Have there been whole-genome studies?

Answer (score 1):

Browsing around GEO, [I see 13 experiments](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gds/?term=yeast%5BOrganism%5D%20microtubule) focusing on microtubule disruption in yeast.

[This CHIP-CHP experiment](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE7276) actually uses nocodazole.

[This is a microarray experiment with benomyl treatment](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE1693).

The rest focus on specific mutants that try to perturb the microtubules in specific ways.

What's more if you broaden the search there is an [extensive body of work](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gds/?term=microtubule) including human cell lines work as well...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you summarize what was discovered? Which genes were downregulated/upregulated/unchanged? Thanks.

Comment: GEO doesn't store results.  I'd have to go and redo the analyses myself....